# lldb Xcode Error CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, xcode, core-bluetooth, lldb

I have an app using CoreBluetooth. When I select a Bluetooth device to connect, I get the lldb error with the following backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2818f, 0x000000018207dbd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
frame #0: 0x000000018207dbd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16
frame #1: 0x00000001882e8ee0 CoreBluetooth`__29-[CBXpcConnection handleMsg:]_block_invoke + 60
frame #2: 0x0000000101191bf0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
frame #3: 0x0000000101191bb0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
frame #4: 0x0000000101197658 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 2096
frame #5: 0x00000001829b4bb0 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
frame #6: 0x00000001829b2a18 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1628
frame #7: 0x00000001828e1680 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
frame #8: 0x0000000183df0088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
frame #9: 0x0000000187758d90 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
* frame #10: 0x0000000100039adc BluetoothLE`main + 136 at AppDelegate.swift:13
frame #11: 0x00000001824828b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

The strange thing is I only get this on my iPad mini 4, not on my iPhone 6...

Please can anybody help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in the Device Console in Xcode to see if there are any illuminating messages?  iOS tends to use daemon processes to handle services like bluetooth, and error messages from them won't go to the regular Xcode debugging console since they aren't hooked up to the stdout of your program.  They will go to the Device Console.  That is in the Devices window, select your device and there is a little disclosure widget on the LLHS of the window that reveals the device console.

Comment: In the Device Console all I get when the lldb comes up is:
`Dec 11 14:03:41 Lukes-iPad diagnosticd[79] <Error>: error evaluating process info - pid: 922, punique: 922`
I get this 4 times in a row

Comment: Is the PID in this error the PID of the process you were debugging?  You can do "expr (int) getpid()" in the lldb Console to see that pid.  If so you might want to file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com, as that will get it to the Bluetooth folks who may be able to help you.